# Extension to stop Firefox stealing keystrokes

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, keyboard-shortcuts

I have to use Firefox with a web app that uses Emacs-like keystrokes, including `ctrl-w` to cut text. My Emacs muscle memory often has me hitting `ctrl-w` without thinking, whereupon my Firefox tab abruptly vanishes, because `ctrl-w` is a Firefox shortcut to close a tab. This is maddening. Unfortunately, this occurs on a network where I have no admin privileges, and cannot even get permission to install any software from outside without divine intervention. I've found no Firefox setting in `about:config` that can stop this -- I've googled and googled, and nothing works.

But it occurs to me that I could write a small Firefox extension that intercepts keystrokes before Firefox proper gets hold of them, and just forwards them to the app. Is this possible? I went through this [post](https://kaiwern.com/posts/2022/02/12/writing-a-simple-firefox-extension/) successfully. Then I tried to write an event listener for keystrokes, following [`onCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/commands/onCommand), as follows,

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log("Keydown:", event);
});

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    console.log("page is fully loaded");

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log('document keydown event');
        console.log('key:', e.key);
        console.log('ctrl:', e.getModifierState('Control'));
    }, false);
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log('keydown event');
    console.log('key:', e.key);
    console.log('ctrl:', e.getModifierState('Control'));
}, false);
```

The `load` event shows up on the console, but nothing else. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `ctrl-w` is a reserved key, which causes problems for my proposed solution above. In Firefox's address field, type in

```
view-source:chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml
```

This shows a list of settings for Firefox. At line 289 or thereabouts, you will see

```
<key id="key_close" 
     data-l10n-id="close-shortcut" 
     command="cmd_close" 
     modifiers="accel" 
     reserved="true"/>
```

`cmd_close` is the command to close the current tab. Now go to

```
view-source:resource:///localization/en-US/browser/browserSets.ftl
```

and you will find the key binding for `ctrl-w`:

```
close-shortcut =
    .key = W
```

There is a zip file `omni.ja` inside the Firefox install where these settings are stored, but without admin privileges they can't be changed. (See [here](https://github.com/fraxx001/patch_omni_ja) for a patch that makes this change.) A less drastic method from user [cor-el](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1378404#answer-1510431) involves adding two JavaScript files to the Firefox installation that will accomplish the same thing. Unfortunately, that also requires admin privileges.

At this point I remembered that Firefox can be installed to a user account *without* admin privileges. After rooting around for a while, I found a Firefox installer. I installed it, dropped the JavaScript from cor-el into it, and *voila*, no more problems with `ctrl-w`.